# How to add product category before product name in woo commerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create the link like this

> /hearing-aids/%product_cat%/%product_cat%-productName

I can change the link but the problem is with `category name` and `-` before the product name.
how we can do it by a function in functions.php

Comment: Can't you do that in permalinks settings?

Comment: @Stender when I put `/hearing-aids/%product_cat%/%product_cat%-` in the setting, WordPress adds a `/` after that and my link become like this `/hearing-aids/product_cat/product_cat-/productName`

Comment: you should be able to do `/%category%/%category%-%postname%/` for posts - Can't see why it should be different for woocommerce and their `%product_cat%/%product_cat%-%product_name%/` ?

Comment: or does woocommerce not have a `custom` setting?

Comment: if so - I would look into the pro version of this - https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/

Comment: very nice support, and basically all perma structures can be changed

Comment: Thanks @Stender i will check the plugin that you share